# Text alignment in the relative layout android

Tags: android, layout

Am trying to inflate a relative layout inside my `Listview` dynamically, However am not able to wrap the text content according to above `ImageView`. Please help to sort it out.

My Relative layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_course"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="#08298A"
        android:text="This is my text view in android example"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Custom List view Code as follows: Am inflating the Relative layout inside the linear layout id my_linear

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_curriculum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/progress_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/course_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_scroller" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please provide your desired image which you set to background.

Answer (score 0):

set `false` to `android:singleLine` in your `TextView` XML as follows...

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

So, updated layout XML will be...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_course"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="#08298A"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="This is my text view in android example"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that and getting the same output. I cant get the remaining text

Comment: So, the problem is that full text of `TextView` isn't showing, am I right?

Comment: Exactly, i want it to wrap and appear in next line

Comment: You should add an sample image to explain how the output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You could try stick the TextView in its own LinearLayout.

Comment: i cant get your answer

Comment: Wrap The TextView in a <LinearLayout></LinearLayout> with the width = match_parent and height to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/img"
    android:text="This dummy text here testttttttttt"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/title_course"
android:layout_width="**match_parent**"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
android:background="#08298A"
android:text="This is my text view in android example"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

You are wrapping content on the width, so the parent width won't matter. Use `match_parent`, it should work. I've also deleted parentBottom and alignRight, not sure if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried `android:width="0dp"` in the `TextView` and am getting the desired output.